# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: push, string-length

I'm trying to learn to program using CodeAcademy and I can't figure out how to fix this code. I'm supposed to make a program that finds my name (Tim) in a block of text. I keep getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and I can't find out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong. Can you guys help?

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){
if(text[i]==="T"){
   for(var j=i; j<myName.length+1;j++){
       hits.push(j);
   }
}
}

var text="Tim went to the store. When he got there, Tim got milk. Isn't Tim the best?";

var myName="Tim"

var hits=[]
if(hits.length =0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else{
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Also, this is the instructions it gives:

*Perfect! You've now got the engine of your search program running. It will:
Loop through the array,
Compare each letter to the first letter of your name, and if it sees that letter:
It will push that letter and all the letters that follow it to an array, stopping when the number of letters it pushes are equal to the number of letters in your name.
Instructions
Under your existing code (and outside all your loops!), set up an if/else statement. If you don't have any hits, log "Your name wasn't found!" to the console. Otherwise, log the hits array to the console.*

Turns out my variables had to be above the rest of the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move:

```
var hits = [];
var text="Tim went to the store. When he got there, Tim got milk. Isn't Tim the best?";
var myName="Tim"
```

above your for loop:

```
var hits = [];
var text="Tim went to the store. When he got there, Tim got milk. Isn't Tim the best?";
var myName="Tim"

for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){
if(text[i]==="T"){
   for(var j=i; j<myName.length+1;j++){
       hits.push(j);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes I moved all my variables above and that fixed it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It says I have to wait 7 minutes, but I'll gladly do it then

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, only the variable declaration is moved to the top of the script (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Variable Initialization is not moved to the top.

So essentially, you original code is transformed as -

```
var text; var myName; var hits; //Only the variables declaration is hoisted to the top.

/*jshint multistr:true */
for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){
if(text[i]==="T"){
   for(var j=i; j<myName.length+1;j++){
       hits.push(j);
   }
}
}

Variables are still initialized in the same place.
text="Tim went to the store. When he got there, Tim got milk. Isn't Tim the best?";
myName="Tim"
hits=[]

if(hits.length =0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else{
    console.log(hits);
}
```

So when the JS engine tried to execute text.length on line 3, text was 'undefined'.